# Why there is no link to the blog in the home?

Tags: support, blog, links

This may sound silly, but I cannot find any link to the Photo-SE blog in the homepage.

It's my blindness or really there isn't one??

EDIT: Actually, there is a *small* link at the bottom of the main page, saying `blog`. Is it enough? Mmm...

Comment: we have a blog?

Answer (score 2):

New blog posts appear in the "Community Bulletin" box on the right-hand side of the page.

Admittedly, this is not the best exposure for the blog, but we're still debating what gets prominence on the top nav; when you have high-rep users and moderators, that top space gets cluttered.

Comment: Honestly, that shouldn't be the priority. The site is made for everyone, not that 5% of high-rep users. Especially, it's made also for non-registered users

Comment: @clabacchio Yes, and it's also made to be a Q&A platform, not a blog platform. The blogs are secondary, which is why they don't get much exposure. Until about 2 months ago, the Photo.SE blog was not updated on a regular basis (like most of the community blogs) - there were *no posts from November 6, 2011 - March 16, 2012*. It looks just as bad to advertise an inactive blog as it does to make the blog difficult to find. But we're working on a way to balance everything out, so thank you for your input.

Comment: of course mine was just a proposal, but I think that the blog fits in the Wiki-style of the site, if not in the Q&A (it's just A without Q ;))

Comment: Honestly, while I like our blog, I don't like how it competes with [this style of post using the main SE engine](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/). I think blog posts should mostly be for time-sensitive or time-limited topics and for opinion pieces. Everything else should go on the main site. For example, [rfusca's nice post on portrait perspective](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/05/portrait-perspective/) would be a stellar answer to http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/916/. The blog should _draw people in_ to the main site, not send people away.

Comment: Not that I'm complaining about @rfusca's good work on the blog, by the way.

Comment: I discovered the blog thanks to this question. There is some great content there. I don't mind whether it takes up space on the top bar or the content is migrated to questions on the main site, but it's too good to waste by letting it linger in obscurity.

Answer (score 0):

The link only shows when there is a recent article for you to read.

Comment: Yes, but the point of a blog is that the content is always interesting, isn't it?